# How do I iterate over a result returned by 'fetch' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, fetch

The following react application should fetch data from a RESTful API when a button is clicked and represent the data as a ul:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class RestSample extends React.Component{ 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [] };
    }

    fetchHotels(event){
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/ui/rest/hotel') 
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({items:data.json()});
            });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={(event)=>this.fetchHotels(event)}>Hotel list</button>
                <ul>
                   {this.state.items.map(function(item){
                       return(
                        <li></li>
                       )
                       })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <RestSample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However, on click I get a 'this.state.items.map is not a function' error because this.state.items is a promise and not a list when render is called.

Where do I have to place the code to iterate over this.state.items to make sure that it is called once the promise has returned a the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
fetchHotels(event){
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/ui/rest/hotel')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json=> {
                this.setState({items:json.data.map(child => child)});
            });
    }
```

Please see https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html for good example .

Comment: This did the trick. The method actually now looks like this:

   fetchHotels(event){
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/ui/rest/hotel')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json=> {
                this.setState({hotels:json.map(child => child)});
            });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should not use map initially , give any condition before using loop or map whether data is available in your variable , if it is then only loop else do some default thing.

Example i have given check once:

```
render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick={(event)=>this.fetchHotels(event)}>Hotel list</button>
                    <ul>
                       {(this.state.items)?this.state.items.map(function(item){
                           return(
                            <li></li>
                           )
                           }):null}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }
```